# Repositioning rendered form in Rails view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a photo carousel application using bootstrap carousel with autoplay disabled. Each photograph has a title, description and an image. Each photograph also has multiple comments (Each photograph has_many :comments & each comment belongs_to :photograph) and a user can add a new comment. Comment creation & display is handled via AJAX (remote: true).

### View

```
<div class="bootstrap-example">
  <div id="carousel-example-captions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <% @photographs.each_index do |i| %>
        <% if i == 0 %>
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-captions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <% else %>
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-captions" data-slide-to=<%= i.to_s %> class=""></li>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <% @photographs.each_index do |i| %>
        <% if i == 0 %>
          <div class="item active">
        <% else %>
          <div class="item">
        <% end %>
        <img src=<%= @photographs.image.url(:high) %>>   
        <div class="carousel-comments">
          <h3> Comments</h3>
          <h4><%= link_to " Add Comment", new_photograph_comment_path(photograph_id: @photographs[i].id), remote: true %></h4>
          <%= render :partial => 'comments', :locals => {comments: @photographs[i].comments} %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-captions" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-captions" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="new-comments-area"></div>
```

The above set up works fine & will produce the necessary form for submitting creating a comment & will display added content. However the form and the comments are displayed within the carousel.

In order to move the comments section outside the carousel, I added a div with class "new-comments-area" & wrote the following javascript using http://jsfiddle.net/xL9PX/2/ as an example

### JS

```
var update_comments;
update_comments = function () {
  $('.carousel').carousel({
    pause: true,
    interval: false
  });
  var comment = $('div.item:nth-child(1) .carousel-comments');
  $('.new-comments-area').html(comment.html());
  comment.css('display', 'none');

  $(".carousel").on('slide.bs.carousel', function (evt) {
    var comment = $('div.item:nth-child(' + ($(evt.relatedTarget).index() + 1) + ') .carousel-comments');
    $('.new-comments-area').html(comment.html());
    comment.css('display', 'none');
  });
};

$(document).ready(update_comments);
```

With this the Comments section is moved down to the "new-comment-area" div as expected, but when I click on the Add Comment link, the form is not rendered anymore. I can confirm the the form is being returned by the rails server & have also noticed the corresponding XHR request in the Google Chrome Devtools. Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Presumably your controller, or a js.erb file, is "doing something" after the action completes?  Perhaps the content of this doesn't match up with your new layout.

Comment: I just noticed that when I click on Add Comment in the "new-comment-area", the form is rendered in the carousel under "carousel-comments" with display set to none. It turned out that there were two instances of id where I wanted to render the form - one within "carousel-comments" & the other within "new-comment-area". After removing the id attribute in "carousel-comments", I was able to get it to work as expected. Thanks for the tip Max Williams